# What is the standard format for a browser's User-Agent string?

Tags: user-agent

Is there an RFC, official standard, or template for creating a User Agent string? The iphone's user-agent string seems strange...

> > Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; **CPU iPhone OS 3_1_2 like Mac OS X**; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (**KHTML, like Gecko**) Version/4.0 Mobile/7D11 Safari/528.16

Comment: The iPhone seriously puts `Mozilla/5.0` at the beginning of it's user agent?

Comment: @Slokun why the surprise? IE user-agent starts with `Mozilla/4.0`. Remember that Mozilla one of the first browsers to be made, and all others include, to various degrees, parts of its foundation.

Comment: The explanation on http://www.useragentstring.com/ is that it should just mean Gecko-based browsers (Netscape and Firefox) but most other browsers include it to say they're Mozilla-compatible.

Comment: Think of `Mozilla/` as "not Lynx".  Generally text-only = not Mozilla-compatible.  Some old WML/HDML feature-phone browsers also don't identify as Mozilla.  (Fun fact: all the browsers before Lynx died of dysentery or were eaten by grues.)

Comment: [everyone pretended to be everyone else, and confusion abounded](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

Comment: See https://github.com/WICG/ua-client-hints for interesting proposal from Mike West to clean the mess.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

***Note:** In June 2022 the IETF (Internet Engineering Task Force) published [`RFC9110`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-user-agent), which obsoleted [`RFC7231`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3), therefore I'm updating this answer with the new RFC information.*

The `User-Agent` header is part of the [`RFC9110`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-user-agent), which describes the HTTP Semantics, where is states:

> The "`User-Agent`" header field contains information about the user agent originating the request, which is often used by servers to help identify the scope of reported interoperability problems, to work around or tailor responses to avoid particular user agent limitations, and for analytics regarding browser or operating system use. A user agent **SHOULD** send a `User-Agent` header field in each request unless specifically configured not to do so.

### EBNF Specification

```
User-Agent = product *( RWS ( product | comment ) )
```

Where `product` is defined as:

```
product         = token ["/" product-version]
product-version = token
token           = 1*tchar
tchar           = "!" / "#" / "$" / "%" / "&" / "'" / "*"
                / "+" / "-" / "." / "^" / "_" / "`" / "|" / "~"
                / DIGIT / ALPHA
                ; any VCHAR, except delimiters
```

And `comment` is defined as:

```
comment     = "(" *( ctext | quoted-pair | comment ) ")"
ctext       = HTAB | SP | %x21-27 | %x2A-5B | %x5D-7E | obs-text
quoted-pair = "\" ( HTAB | SP | VCHAR | obs-text )
obs-text    = %x80-ff
```

Other rules for reference:

```
HTAB  = <ASCII horizontal tab %x09, aka '\t'>
SP    = <ASCII space, i.e. " ">
VCHAR = <any visible US-ASCII character>
DIGIT = <digits from 0 to 9>
ALPHA = <letters>
RWS   = 1*( SP | HTAB )
1*    = <One or more>
```

Note that this means that `product` cannot contain spaces, but `comments` can.

---

### Examples:

Here are some valid examples of `product` strings (with and without `product-version` strings):

```
# Single `product` without product-version:
Foobar
Foobar-baz

# Single `product` with product-version:
Foobar/abc
Foobar/1.0.0
Foobar/2021.44.30.15-b917dc
```

Here are some valid examples of `comment` strings; note how all strings are enclosed in matched parentheses `(` `)`:

```
# This was the default `comment` used by Internet Explorer 11:
(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)

# You can put almost any text inside a comment:
(Why are you looking at HTTP headers? Go outside, find love, do some good in the world)

# Note that `comment` strings can also be nested, provided their delimiting parentheses are matched, for example:
(Outer comment (Inner comment))
```

As a `User-Agent` header's value is comprised of arbitrary `product` and `comment` strings, these are all valid `User-Agent` headers:

```
User-Agent: Foobar
User-Agent: Foobar/2021.44.30.15-b917dc
User-Agent: MyProduct Foobar/2021.44.30.15-b917dc
User-Agent: Tsom/OfraHaza (Life is short and love is always over in the morning) AnotherProduct
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. There doesn't appear to be a standard format for the comment field.

Comment: What is "quoted-pair"?

Comment: quoted-pair    = "\" CHAR

Comment: Some examples of this, for readers unfamiliar with EBNF, would be ideal. (=

Comment: The referenced RFC is now obsolete. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231 obviates it.

Comment: Funnily enough, RFC 7231 specifically calls out "us[ing] the product tokens of other implementations in order to declare compatibility with them" as a Bad Idea.

Comment: Can the User-Agent string be in any character set? Can it contain for example Russian or Chinese characters?

Comment: @Liam In the absence of any explicit language in the RFC, I would assume it best to stick to 7-bit ASCII. It's hard to imagine a situation where deviating from this would be required, or indeed even useful; the User-Agent: is not intended for human end-user consumption. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-8.3.1 contains some suggestions though I have not spent too much time figuring out if that's authoritatively applicable here.

Comment: @tripleee I have seen some Russian characters which seemed to indicate a student edition of Windows, not sure if it was genuine though. Thanks.

Comment: In _So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish,_ Douglas Adams wrote "The CIA denied it, which means it must be true!" Similarly, if Microsoft is doing something, you can be pretty sure it's wrong and dumb.

Comment: Found a Russian example: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Студент; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)`. It's also XP and MSIE 8.0, so I'm not going to invest more time in this!

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE I added some examples now

Comment: What does `1*` mean?

Comment: @darw: `1*` means "one or more". `*` is the repetition operator in ABNF notation. (The ABNF notation used by RFC 1945 is described in section 2.1 of the RFC.)

Answer (score 11):

This is specified in [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.15) in the section on Request Headers. It is not a very standardized format, though, and user agents tend to put whatever they want in there.

Comment: Thx! Your answer combined with Paulo's make the complete answer.

Comment: You're welcome! It looks like Paulo's is actually more complete and up-to-date, so feel free to mark his as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see: [mozilla website](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/build/revised-user-agent-strings.html), but as it was mentioned before. Basically you can put whatever you want there. For statistical/analytical  purposes, the most important thing is, that every browser/os should have this standardized for itself.