# HttpRequestMessage UserAgent with Colon

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to send a request that has its User Agent set to something with a colon in it, but `HttpRequestMessage` is complaining that the colon is an invalid character.

The exact code looks something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("some-uri"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post
    };

request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Sample:Text");

// then send the request...
```

I looked through [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2601492/1959230) where you can see the EBNF of the User Agent and [this RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html) which specifies what a CTL is.

The first link says that the following is a valid User Agent:

`token = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>`

And the second link defines a CTL as:

`any US-ASCII control character  (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)`

But, colon (`:`) is 58 on the ASCII table, so I don't see why this is a problem.

I assumed that `HttpRequestMessage` does not like colons in it because it's not escaped -- it probably thinks it's a separator. But I tried escaping it in single quotes, double quotes, etc.

Is there a way to escape it that I'm missing?

Or in other words, how do I properly send a colon (`:`) in the User Agent header of an `HttpRequestMessage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an escaping issue like I suspected. It doesn't seem that `HttpRequestMessage` handles automatic escaping.

I'm able to use `Uri.EscapeDataString()` to convert the colon before adding it to the `User-Agent` header. When I process the User-Agent on the endpoint, I have to use `Uri.UnescapeDataString()`

Not too pretty, but it seems to work.