# Android Set default User agent header for android request

Tags: android, request, user-agent

Hi I'm developing a HTTP Webrequest send to back end server to retrive information. How We can set the default header so that backend and can recognize where the request come from (android devices, system version...)

something like: `request.setHeader = ["User-Agent, "...."]`

similar to `system`.`getdefaultUserAgent...`

Purpose to help server filter out which request come from mobile devices, which request is not.

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using httpclient

```
final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT);
        httpParameters.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "your user agent");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know how to set the header. My question is how get the default useragent (contain android devices, OS version...) so that each request will send these info to server?

Comment: oh ok, in my case i have organized myself user agent with these informations, accordingly with UserAgent spec. I don't know ho to get the default one, sorry

Comment: so the purpose is to help server to identify request come from android devices. Do you know how can we achieve that?

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to set default useragent over defaultuseragent. i mean: default user agent should be sent automatically, or i'm mistaking? However, setting up a custom useragent let the server to identify it. what is your doubt?

Comment: for my search android does not send user-agent by default (send null instead). Yes the purpose is to identify the request from mobile user and filter out (reject request) those are not (for security reason)

Comment: so adding a custom useragent that respect RFC2616 should solve your problem. Generate it and add to header, no? You can find a simplified explanation of useragent standard here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601372/what-is-the-standard-format-for-a-browsers-user-agent-string

Comment: Thanks, I 'll try. Do you have sample User-Agent string that we can use?